# Before trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have 2 tables: `survey (id(PK), name)` and `survey_to_topic (survey_id(PK,FK,not null), topic_id(PK,FK,not null))`. When I try to delete from survey table, I get exception:

> "The DELETE statement conflicted with
>   the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_survey _to _topic _survey". The
>   conflict occurred in database
>   "mydatabase", table
>   "dbo.survey _to _topic", column
>   'survey _id'."

So to get no error first I must delete record from table survey_to_topic and after that from table survey. I think it is better to do with before trigger on table survey, but I can't find any information about this. There are a lot of articles about before triggers in PL/SQL, but I use SQL Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add ON DELETE CASCADE to the relationship between the two tables, and the records from the survey_to_topic table will be deleted automatically.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use ON DELETE CASCADE. This is added to the table containing the FK.

See example [here](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/General/using_constraints.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Deem and astander already mentioned - you should use ON DELETE CASCADE on your foreign key relationship - that handles this scenario automatically for you.

SQL Server doesn't know the concept of BEFORE (operation) TRIGGERs - SQL Server has AFTER triggers, or then INSTEAD OF triggers. See the [Introduction to triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-ii) article for some background info.

But ON DELETE CASCADE is definitely the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else here mentioned, `ON DELETE CASCADE` is a way to go -- as long as you are aware of consequences; there is a reason why `ON DELETE NO ACTION` (raise error) is the default. In other words, you should plan your deletion strategy -- it is too easy to wipe out rows from several tables unintentionally by using `ON DELETE CASCADE`.